# Powershell fails to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using SQL Server Management Studio version 15.0.18358.0 and I am trying to automate a Flat File SQL Server Imports With PowerShell. I am not an administrator (not sure if that matters). This is my first time attempting such a query as I am completely new to using PowerShell - I referenced the following link which is very useful:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3208/automating-flat-file-sql-server-imports-with-powershell/.

I basically copy and pasted the code in the link and made edits to the following lines:

```
$connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $ENTSQL01LSNR + ";Database=" + $EMTCQIData + ";integrated security=true"

AutoImportCommaFlatFiles -location "Q:\Data Requests\ED TO BED TEST\" -file "ED_TO_BED_DAILY" -extension ".txt" -server "ENTSQL01LSNR" -database "EMTCQIData"
```

After making these edits, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not 
accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection 
to SQL Server)"
At line:21 char:5
+     $connection.Open()
```

Full Code

```
Function AutoImportCommaFlatFiles($location, $file, $extension, $server, $database)
{
    $full = $location + $file + $extension
    $all = Get-Content $full
    $columns = $all[0]
    $columns = $columns.Replace(" ","")
    $columns = $columns.Replace(",","] VARCHAR(100), [")
    $table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + "([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(100))"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $buildTable = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $insertData = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $ENTSQL01LSNR + ";Database=" + $EMTCQIData + ";integrated security=true"
    $buildTable.CommandText = $table
    $buildTable.Connection = $connection
    ## Added to function
    $x = 0
    $insertData.CommandText = "EXECUTE stp_CommaBulkInsert @1,@2"
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@1", $full)
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@2", $file)
    $insertData.Connection = $connection
    $connection.Open()
    $buildTable.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
    ## Added to function
    $x = 1
    if ($x = 1)
    {
        $connection.Open()
        $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $connection.Close()
    }
}
AutoImportCommaFlatFiles -location "Q:\Data Requests\ED TO BED TEST\" -file "ED_TO_BED_DAILY" -extension ".txt" -server "ENTSQL01LSNR" -database "EMTCQIData"
```

Comment: Have you checked that the connection string is turning out how you expect it to?  You don't include where the $ENTSQL01LSNR  or $EMTCQIData variables are set, so that could be where this is going wrong.

Comment: You don't connect things to SQL Server Management Studio. SSMS is a client that connects to SQL Servers, just like Outlook is a client that connects to mail servers. Does `$ENTSQL01LSNR` hold details of your own workstation, or details of an actual SQL Server?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but that's just because I'm a newb but ENTSQL01LSNR is the "Server Name" when I start and login into SQL.

Comment: @MikeShepard  $ENTSQL01LSNR corresponds to the "Server Name" and $EMTCQIData corresponds to the database where all of my tables are stored. I have not checked the connection string - not really sure how to check that.

Comment: Are those the names of the server/database or the names of variables containing the names of the server/database?  If those are the actual names, you don't want $ on them and you'll need to quote them.

Comment: You're using the wrong variables in the connection string.
Replace $ENTSQL01LSNR by $server and $EMTCQIData by $database inside the AutoImportCommaFlatFiles function.

Comment: @MikeShepard they are the actual names of the server/database

Comment: @Fabricio has it.  You should be using $server and $database insted of $ENTSQL01LSNR and $EMTCQIData

Comment: thanks all these worked but I am not getting another error which I will raise in a separate question